# Akka.net faulttolerance, SuperVisorStrategy and losing the message that caused the exception

Tags: akka.net

I'm having a look at Akka.net faulttolerance and have setup a simple sample where Actor1 tells Actor2 a message. Actor2 throws an exception. Actor1 has a SuperVisorStrategy which tells the failing actor to resume.

I actually expected that the message would be passed again to Actor2. But that's not the case. So Actor2 resumes and can continue processing new messages. 
But now the message that made the Actor fail, is gone. How should this be handled? I don't want to lose the message that caused the exception. I would like that Actor2 is processing the message again.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("test"))
            {
                IActorRef customer = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<Actor1>(), "actor1");

                customer.Tell(new Start());
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Actor1 : UntypedActor
    {
        protected override SupervisorStrategy SupervisorStrategy()
        {
            return new OneForOneStrategy(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ex =>
            {
                if (ex is ApplicationException)
                    return Directive.Resume;

                return Directive.Escalate;
            });
        }

        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            if (message is Start)
            {
                IActorRef actor2Ref = Context.ActorOf<Actor2>("actor2");
                Context.Watch(actor2Ref);

                actor2Ref.Tell(new DoSomething());
            }

            else if (message is Response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response received");
                return;
            }
            else if (message is Terminated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Terminated");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Actor2 : UntypedActor
    {
        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            if (message is DoSomething)
            {
                // only called once.
                throw new ApplicationException("testexception");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Start
    {
    }

    public class DoSomething
    {
    }

    public class Response
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the following in the Akka documentation. The message is gone indeed.


What happens to the Message
If an exception is thrown while a message is being processed (i.e. taken out of its mailbox and handed over to the current behavior), then this message will be lost. It is important to understand that it is not put back on the mailbox. So if you want to retry processing of a message, you need to deal with it yourself by catching the exception and retry your flow.

Comment: Make sure that you put a bound on the number of retries since you don't want a system to livelock (so consuming a lot of cpu cycles without making progress). Another possibility would be to have a look at the PeekMailbox pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's quite unlikely, that you would like to re-process the same error-prone message several times in a row. If it's causing an exception, processing it again and again in the same millisecond will probably bring exactly same result.

What you **might** want to achieve, is trying to reprocess it after some delay i.e. because you're trying to reconnect to an external service. In this case you may want to wrap it into another message and schedule resend in ActorSystem scheduler. Basic example:

```cs
sealed class Retry
{
    public readonly object Message;
    public readonly int Ttl;

    public Retry(object message, int ttl)
    {
        Message = message;
        Ttl = ttl;
    }
}

class MyActor : ReceiveActor 
{
    ...

    protected override void PreRestart(Exception reason, object message)
    {
        Retry oldRetry;
        var retry = (oldRetry = message as Retry) != null 
            ? new Retry(oldRetry.message, oldRetry.Ttl - 1)
            : new Retry(message, retryCount);

        if (retry.Ttl > 0)
            Context.System.Scheduler.ScheduleTellOnce(delay, Self, retry, Sender);

        base.PreRestart(reason, message);
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs some other cases may also involve using [CircuitBreakers](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/C375EDE2.htm) or more reliable delivery semantic - by default Akka.NET provides at-most-once delivery semantic, you can change this using AtLeastOnceDelivery components from Akka.Persistence plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Reprocess the same message again depends on the type of exception. Let's say transient vs non-transient exceptions. Just like nservicebus by default is first trying to process the same message five times. After that, the second level retry comes in.